# python not able to read a file that exists

Tags: python

I wrote the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

########
N = 92 
lookup  = 'The forecast spread is'
    iday_start    = 1 
    iday_end      = 1
    year        = 2013
    month       = 07  
    extension_type1  = '-RTPSinfl.dat'
    extension_type2  = 'engl_var_anal.'
    extension        = 2
######### Append the files into files
    for iday in range (iday_start, iday_end+1):
        day =  str(0) + str(iday) 
        for itime in range(0,24,6) :   
           if itime < 12: 
           ihour = str(0) + str(itime)
        else:
           ihour =  str(itime) 
        if extension == 1 :  
          file  = str(year)+str(month) + day + ihour + extension_type1
          print(file)  
        elif  extension == 2 :
          file = extension_type2 + str(year)+str(month)+day+ihour+'.1.out'
          print(file)         
#========          
      f = open(file)
      lines = f.readlines()
      f.close() 
      with open(file) as myFile:
          for num, line in enumerate(myFile,1):
              if lookup in line:
                  print 'found at line:', num  
          num = num+2
          numN = num + N
          lrange = range(num,numN)
          for l in lrange:
                for ii in range(0,7): 
                    nstart = numN + ii * (N+2) + 1
                    lrange = range(nstart,nstart+N)
                    for l in lrange:
                        print lines[l],                 
      myFile.close()
```

and here is the error message

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'engl_var_anal.201370100.1.out'
```

The file engl_var_anal.201370100.1.out does exists.

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place, can you please clean it up?

Comment: And a file may well exist **somewhere** on your harddisk, but not in the current working directory of the script. Use a full path instead.

Comment: @user3270373: If you are satisfied with my answer please accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Python will load the file from the directory you are running the script from, **NOT** from the location of the script. If this doesn't help could you maybe give us the exact command you are running and the full path of where that file is?

**Edit**:

One thing to look for is that you have the exact same number of digits in the filename as your program is outputting. This is a common mistake when dealing with printing digits to strings. It looks like you expect your month to be 2 digits "07", but your output filename only has 1. Double check this.

If you need 2 digits do some kind of string formatting like:

```
file = extension_type2 + "%04d%02d%02d%04d" % (year, month, day, ihour) + ".1.out"
```

Or use datetime objects and strftime to format a date/time.

If you `cd /dir/with/files_and_script`, then run `ls -l` (assuming linux shell) and you see "test.py" and "engl_var_anal.201370100.1.out" and then run `python`, ...some code..., `execfile("test.py")`...this should work.

Comment: Thanks. I do run the script and load the file from the same location.  I use the following command  execfile('test.py') in the  python2.7 interpreter.

Comment: @user3270373: either your working directory isn't what you think it is (try `import os; print(os.getcwd())`, the file's not really there, or you have a serious problem where your filesystem is reporting that files don't exist when they do. The first 2 options seem the most likely.

Comment: @user3270373 Take a look at my edit. I think you might not have as many digits in the filename as you expect.